# Quarkus Amazon S3 NoSuckBucketException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, quarkus

When working with Amazon S3 and Quarkus, I encountered a challenging issue where the S3 bucket was not being recognized or found. This was perplexing, as all the configurations and credentials seemed correct. I double-checked the AWS credentials and the bucket name to ensure they were accurately set in the Quarkus application properties.

I then looked into the Quarkus documentation for any specific requirements or configurations that might be different from standard AWS SDK usage. I wondered if there were additional steps or configurations in Quarkus for integrating with S3, like specific client customizations or policy settings.

After ensuring the setup was correct, I started troubleshooting the network and permissions. I checked if the S3 bucket was in a different region than the one specified in the configuration, as this could cause the bucket not to be found. I also verified the IAM roles and policies to ensure that the application had the necessary permissions to access the S3 bucket. Everything is configured correctly and the same error always occurs, where the bucket is not found.

My application.properties:

```
bucket.name=bucket-test-flower

quarkus.s3.aws.region=us-east-1
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.type=static
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.static-provider.access-key-id=my-key
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.static-provider.secret-access-my-other-key
```

My Code:

Here

```
public class S3SyncClientResource extends CommonResource {
    @Inject
    S3Client s3;

    @POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(FormData formData) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(bucketName);
        System.out.println(formData.data);
        System.out.println(formData.filename);
        System.out.println(formData.mimetype);

        if (formData.filename == null || formData.filename.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        if (formData.mimetype == null || formData.mimetype.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        PutObjectResponse putResponse = s3.putObject(buildPutRequest(formData),
                RequestBody.fromFile(formData.data));
        if (putResponse != null) {
            return Response.ok().status(Status.CREATED).build();
        } else {
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }
    }
```

```
abstract public class CommonResource {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "bucket.name")
    protected
    String bucketName;

    protected PutObjectRequest buildPutRequest(FormData formData) {
        return PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(formData.filename)
                .contentType(formData.mimetype)
                .build();
    }

    protected GetObjectRequest buildGetRequest(String objectKey) {
        return GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(objectKey)
                .build();
    }

}
```

```
public class FormData {

    @RestForm("file")
    public File data;

    @RestForm
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String filename;

    @RestForm
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String mimetype;

}
```

The error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchBucketException: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: S3, Status Code: 404, Request ID: 5a31b1b4-e4cf-449d-b307-78271669c94b, Extended Request ID: s9lzHYrFp76ZVxRcpX9+5cjAnEH2ROuNkd2BHfIa6UkFVdtjf5mKR3/eTPFvsiP/XV/VLi31234=)
```